# Access to class variable from within objects that are part of same class

Tags: c++, simulation, modeling

I'm building a molecular dynamics simulation from scratch to practice my new c++ skills and I've run into some trouble.

Inside the simulation 'box' object, I have a private variable L that contains the length of the system.
Also Inside 'box' object I have a vector of 'particle' objects (not derived in any way from 'box'). A 'particle' object contains the particle's normalized position (0 to 1 in each dimension).
I need a way to access L from within the 'particle' object. I need this so that I can use it to multiply the normalized position in order to get the actual position when needed (the normalized position is more convenient to work with most of the time).

This access to L should be read-only, and not generate a copy of L, but rather all particles should refer to the same L in case it is changed (e.g. box is expanded).

I thought of maybe passing to each 'particle' object a const reference to L when they are initialized.
Is this really the best way?
Is there a way to do it that doesn't involve passing something to each 'particle' object in its constructor? (because I might have to pass many more such "state variables" to each 'particle')

Thanks.

Edit: I'm attaching code and addressing @1201ProgramAlarm 's suggestion which seems to make sense but I had problems implementing:

***Particle_Class.h***

```
class Box_Class;
class point;
class Particle_Class
{
public:
    Particle_Class(Box_Class &box);
private:
    const Box_Class &box;
    point velByL;
};
```

***Particle_Class.cpp***

```
Particle_Class::Particle_Class(Box_Class &box)
        :box(box){}

void Particle_Class::init_P(const point pt){velByL=pt*box.get_L()/mass; return ;};
```

***Box_Class.cpp***

```
for (int i=0;i<initN;i++)
    particle.emplace_back(*this);
```

Unfortunately I get a compiler error at the line void Particle_Class::init_P

"error: invalid use of incomplete type 'const class Box_Class'|"

Comment: Can you include your code in your post?  It may make it easier for you to get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a pointer to the `box` object to the `particle` objects, and provide a getter method in `box` for `L`.  This pointer could be passed in to the constructor of `particle`, and stored within the object, or can be passed to the member functions of `particle` that need access to it.

Comment: I didn't think of passing the reference to the box object, instead of passing references to each state parameter on it's own. Great, this should work.

Comment: But now I'm running into trouble with the implementation. I get error: invalid use of incomplete type 'const class Box_Class (see edited post)

Comment: @YoavPollack Sounds like you need to include the Box_Class header in particle_class.cpp.

Comment: gee 10x. I've had previous problems with this error due to other reasons, so I forgot the problem might be that trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Since `particle` only has a normalised position, what determine the actual position of the particle is `box`. So your `box` object should have a method to return the real position of a given particle:

```
struct Particle { float x, y; /* maybe other properties */ };
struct Position { float x, y; };

struct Box {
    Position position(Particle const& p) {
        return {p.x * L, p.y * L};
    }

private:
    float L;
};
```

That way, you don't need `particle` to use `box`, and you don't need `particle` to access a private member of box, and you don't need an accessor.

---

*Would the particle knowing it's real position better?*

The answer is no. The particle don't need to know it's real position.

Let's say you have a bunch of particle somewhere you would like to draw in a box, then you will not only need the particle, but the box too. But the particle in itself don't need the box.

It also makes it trivial to move particle from one box to another: you only need to send a different box to the drawing function and/or move the vector of particle to the other box's vector. No copying, no changing references, no problem.

Comment: your solution seems to be the best one in terms of OOP. However after consideration I decided not to use it as it will mean using normalized units everywhere in the box class which will be a nuisance and could lead to mistakes on my part. Thanks though!

Comment: @YoavPollack You could create a wrapper around a pointer to particle and a pointer to  box named `BoxedParticle` that has a `normalized()` and `real()` accessors, and pass this wrapper where you need particles with their real position. It even has the potential of being faster and more memory efficient and also has all the advantage of my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a getter method in box to allow access to L.  It might look something like

```
public:
    int GetL(){
        return L;
    }
```

Then, have your `particle` objects call that method to read the value of L.

If a public accessor to L is undesirable (perhaps for security reasons), you could declare the particles as a friend.  This is a c++ feature that allows the particles to directly private members of box.  Some people consider "friend" to be bad coding practice.  It also leads to jokes about friends being allowed to access private members.

```
friend particles[];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, L is a private part of your implementation and you don't wish to expose a public getter in your interface.

One solution I have used in the past is to create a helper class that exposes the state shared between the two classes -- in this case it might be called BoxParticleInterface.

The interface can be created by Box and passed to Particle on construction.

```
class BoxParticleInterface
{
    BoxParticleInterface( L const & l, Etc const & etc ) : l_( l ) { }
    L const & l() { return l_; }
    L l_;
}
```

This might be more useful than passing a single reference / pointer around in that:
a) it logically groups the members that are passed from Box to Particle, and
b) it's a little easier to extend if you have more state that you want to communicate.